# ActiveCollab HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

Tags: http-status-code-403, http-1.1, activecollab

I am facing a strange issue with `ActiveCollab` Project Management Tool.

> Whenever I create ticket and assign it to other user they are not able to see the item (access it via url) at all even though I can clearly see that they have been added to the item. It's giving the users HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden.

I need everyone to gain access to these `tickets` without changing their `access permissions`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

403 Forbidden is what it says it is: Access not allowed due to insufficient permissions.

Make sure that users have permissions to access given project section. You can see which permissions user has in each section of a project on project's `People` page. In activeCollab 2, you access it via `People` tab for each project, and in activeCollab 3 you have `Manage Project People` option on project overview page.